# ASP.Net Display value for radio button selected on my confirmationpage

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a 4pg `ASP.NET` form which is storing data in the session and the button on my 3rd page clears the session.  All this is working fine but I'm having 2 problems with my radio buttons.

**First Problem**

On my confirmation page (Pg3) its displaying 'True' or 'False'. I want the value to be 'Yes' or 'No'. How do I do this

**Second Problem**

How do I only display the selected value on my confirmation pg? I know if needs to be wrapped in an `IF` statement but I'm unsure how to write it complete brain fart I'm afraid.

**HTML for the page with my radio button on**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Do you have kids?"></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline">
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="pg2Yes" value="Yes" GroupName="ABC"/> Yes
                    </asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" class="radio-inline">
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="pg2No" value="No" GroupName="ABC"/> No
                    </asp:Label>
                </div>
```

**Code behind for the above**

```
protected void pg2button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["pg2"] = txtData2.Text;
    Session["pg2Yes"] = pg2Yes.Checked;
    Session["pg2No"] = pg2No.Checked;
    Response.Redirect("/Session/pg3.aspx");
}
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Confirmation page HTML**

```
        <% if (pg2Yes == true) {%>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Kids?"></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-control-static">
                    <%=Session["pg2Yes"] %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%}
        else
        {%>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" class="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Kids?"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 form-control-static">
                        <%=Session["pg2No"] %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <%} %>
```

It says for my `IF` statement I get the following error:

*The name 'pg2Yes' does not exist in the current context*

If I declare a `variable` at the top, something like:

```
<% var pg2Yes == false; %>
```

I get the following error:

*Implicitly-types local variables must be initialized*

I'm completely new to coding and not sure how to do this

Comment: did you declare it using 'var' ?

Comment: @trainoasis Yes, for some reason it was in my post but was not displaying.  I have re-added it and it's now showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem:**
Change `pg2button_Click` to:

```
Session["pg2Yes"] = pg2Yes.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
Session["pg2No"] = pg2No.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
```

This way, you store "Yes" and "No" instead of the boolean values "True" and "False"

**Second Problem:**
Try changing `<% if (pg2Yes == true) {%>` to (this is assuming you also do the change for the first problem):

```
<% if (Session["pg2Yes"] == "Yes") {%>
```